# Error http 405 en Android

Tags: android, http, post

Estoy haciendo una aplicación Android y cuando hago una petición POST aparece el error 405 method not allowed. ¿Cómo  puedo arreglar el problema para poder realizar la petición satisfactoria?

Comment: Agrega tu código y tu url si es posible,la url que intentas llamar mediante POST no soporta este método.

Comment: Como todos te comentan tu error es que el metodo que estas intentando llamar en tu API no soporta las peticiones  POST. Prueba llamando a tu misma URL pero GET y verifica si funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Ese error es una respuesta del servidor que te dice que ese método no está permitido. ¿Estas enviando bien la petición al servidor?

Comment: Si, los envía bien porque cuando estoy conectado por wifi no me sale el error y me los envía. Hay megas en el móvil y hay conexión.

Comment: Puedes dar más datos? Si te funciona con WiFi pero no con 3g algo tiene que haber diferente... por cierto he editado cambiando "los datos" por " la petición". El servidor lo que te dice es que el método post no está permitido, puede ser que no tengas permisos para usarlo. Tal vez cambie algo en la consulta con 3g frente a la consulta wifi. Sin verlo más profundamente no te se decir.

Answer (score 1):

Cómo bien te indica @idelcano el error es en la solicitud de la Api, `el método POST no está permitido` para la operación.

Mira la documentación de la API/RESTFUL del webservicio que quieres usar.

También puedes replicar la operación, usando una herramienta de test de peticiones de API/RestFul como por ejemplo [resttesttest](https://resttesttest.com/) cuando lo consigues puedes replicarlo en el código de Android.

Answer (score 0):

> POST aparece el error 405 method not allowed

Cuando realizas la petición obtienes este error simplemente porque no se tiene implementado tu url la capacidad de recibir peticiones por el método POST.

Como solucionarlo? La url debe soportar el método POST.